# How can i debug a xform submission?

Tags: xml, xhtml, xquery, xforms, exist-db

i'm having trouble debbuging an xform in a xhtml file. Previously it was working, but now i changed something in the namespaces of the xf:model and now when i press the submit button it doesn't do anything. I'll give a simple example in order for you to better understand my issue, but keep in mind that i'm working in a xhtml file with 400+ lines and i've been losing hours (almost 40 hours in the last week) debugging line by line, and trial and error to find out what's wrong with my forms.

```
    <html namespaces come here>
    <head>
       <title>Example</title>
       <xf:model schema="foobar.xsd">
         <xf:instance>
            <Persons xmlns="">
               <name></name>
            </Persons>
         <xf:/instance>
       </xf:model>
       <xf:bind id=name nodeset="/Person/aluno" type="xs:string"/>
       <xf:submission id="submit" action="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/foo/bar.xquery" method="post"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Type the name of the Person</h1>
      <xf:input bind="name">
       <xf:label>
                <b>Name:</b>
       </xf:label>
      </xf:input>
      <xf:submit submission="submit">
        <xf:label>SUBMIT</xf:label>
      </xf:submit>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ok, this is a simple example (it can have some errors, doesn't matter), but imagine that everytime i press SUBMIT it doesn't do anything. **How can i find what is causing the error?**

Comment: What i means is, is there some debugging tool i can use?

Comment: Are you using BetterFORM or XSLTForms as XForms engine???

Comment: @loveMeansNothing lol, that made really made my laugh :) I am sure Alain wanted to know which XForm engine you are using of these two. But I have to say, strictly speaking your answer is correct :-)

Comment: @dirkk thanks for pointing that out, i'm just really tired LOL

Comment: @Alain Couthures I'm using BetterFORM

Comment: @loveMeansNothing have you consulted `$EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB-INF/logs/betterform.log` and if so, anything revealing? Also have you switched on the debugging bar in betterForm? See the property `betterform.debug-allowed` in `$EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB-INF/betterform-config.xml`.

Comment: @adamretter i've activated the debug mod and now i'm able to see what i send to the form.

Comment: Throught the log i can find this and i suspect this is what is causing the issue:

Comment: Caused by: de.betterform.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsException: de.betterform.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsInternalSubmitException: 400: Unknown XML root element: wiki:article_container: resource-error
 at de.betterform.connector.http.HTTPSubmissionHandler.submit(Unknown Source)... 53 more
Caused by: de.betterform.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsInternalSubmitException: 400: Unknown XML root element: wiki:article_container: resource-error
 at de.betterform.connector.http.AbstractHTTPConnector.execute(Unknown Source)
 at de.betterform.connector.http.AbstractHTTPConnector.post(Unknown Source)... 54 more

Comment: @loveMeansNothing Can you show the document that is being sent to the server that is causing the HTTP 400?

Comment: @adamretter the xml document looks like this: http://pastebin.com/BMmwND9i

I've used it as src at the <xf:instance/> in the xhtml, it looks like this:
<xf:instance src="http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/wiki/templates/add_article_template.xml"/>

Comment: @loveMeansNothing Hmm that does not help me much. I guess I am missing the full picture. I will see if I cannot attract one of the betterForm guys to this...

Comment: @adamretter that would be lovely. 
This is what the betterform.log looks like when i try to submit: http://pastebin.com/SeHi0FJr

Comment: keep getting:
Caused by: de.betterform.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsInternalSubmitException: 400: Bad Request: resource-error

But i'm pretty sure my resource is accessible..

Answer (score 0):

@loveMeansNothing following the error message: "Unknown XML root element: wiki:article_container" you haven't declared the namespace xmlns:wiki="http://www.generic-wiki.org/Wiki" on the 'html' element? Further you are missing the xforms @replace attribute on your submission which means it defaults to replace="all" (following the XForms W3C recommendation), have you tried to use @repalce="none" or @replace="instance" here (depending on what you want to archive)?

Regarding debugging of betterFORM @adamretter already pointed out where to find the logs and how the enable the debug bar. Further you could add a xforms-submit-error handler to your submission:

```
<xf:submission id="..." ...>
  <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-error">
    <xf:message>Submit Error! Resource-uri: <xf:output value="event('resource-uri')"/>
                Response-reason-phrase: <xf:output value="event('response-reason-phrase')"/>
    </xf:message>
  </xf:action>
</xf:submission>
```

and I often use Firebug for debugging purposes.

If this all doesn't solve your issue it would be great to have a running example of your form to reproduce the error.

Comment: i've done that and now i always get this this error when i submit: http://tinypic.com/r/bi1c91/8

The resource is called like this, it has permissions to execute:
<xf:submission id="submit" action="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/peitp14/logic/added_article.xquery" method="post"/>

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've found the solution!

It was missing a stupid slash on the xquery called by the

```
      <xf:submission id="submit" action="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/myapp/logic/action.xquery" method="post"/>
```

if looked like this:

```
let $store:=xmldb:store('db/apps/myapp/data','test.xml', $newArticle)
```

while it should look this (see the slash):

```
let $store:=xmldb:store('/db/apps/myapp/data','test.xml', $newArticle)
```

Also i've created a new user and added him to the 'dba' group throught the exist-db Java Admin Client. After that i've created a the new application on exide **using the new username credentials.** Also used that user here:

```
   let $login:=xmldb:login('/db/apps/myapp','user','password')
```

Thanks for the help people :)